# Пропадает доступ в интернет при соединении через CiscoAnyConnect к корпоративной сети

Tags: сеть, vpn, настройка, cisco

Был провайдер "Ростелеком":

- Никаких настроек роутера, либо соединений на ПК я не выполнял.
  Работал удаленно в сети компании через CiscoAnyConnect подключаясь
  стандартно через логин/пароль.  Работал и VPN и интернет с ПК.

Изменился провайдер на "МГТС":

- также никаких настроек не выполнялось, в сети компании настройки так
  же не менялись. После подключения пропадает доступ в интернет вообще
  ко всем ресурсам, даже к тем что разрешены в сети компании (к слову
  там почти ничего и не запрещено)

Связывался с МГТС, сказали помочь не могут, это надо настройки у вашей компании смотреть, хотя в компании ничего не менялось. У коллег продолжает работать и интернет и VPN на других провайдерах и Ростелекоме, ничего дополнительного не настраивали.

Сталкивался ли кто-то? гуглил, галочки всякие в сетевом соединении вкл/выкл и тому подобное, ничего не помогло пока что.

Все что откопал в интернете, это изменение настроек стандартного подключения VPN, которое поднимается в самой Windows, а не через CiscoAnyConnect

UPD: Со сменой провайдера роутер тоже поменялся, был DLINK, стал стандартный МГТС от ZTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо в свойствах соединения убрать галку с "IP версии 6(TCP/IP)"
Почему протокол мешает трафику пока мне не известно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за совет!!! Убрал галку "IP версии 6 (TCP/IPv6) и интернет страницы начали открываться.

Comment: у меня такая же проблема была - но просто написал админам, которые впн настраивают, они репу почесали и все сделали.